# Revision description doesn’t fit in page

Tags: bug, design, revisions-list, responsive-design, mobile-chrome

Because long single words don't wrap, in particular links, the description in the revision may overflow the page width.

E.g. [here](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/271519/revisions):

> [image: Word wrapping needed]

This also affects long enough user names like [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/387169/revisions):

> [image: Long user name]

Comment: I can reproduce this with Mobile Chrome also on English-language sites (e.g., https://tex.stackexchange.com/posts/419533/revisions), so it is unrelated to the Cyrillic script in the question. On desktop the issue does not occur.

Comment: @Marijn I never stated that it was Cyrillic related issue. Did you try to reduce the browser window width on desktop?

Comment: I know that you didn't state it, I thought it may or may not be related so I tested it out, and indeed it is not related to the script so I thought that would be a good comment to make in case other people also considered that it may or may not be related.

Comment: Regarding desktop browsers: initially I tried only Firefox. There I reduced the browser width, then words wrap (and the font becomes smaller) and the url is wrapped on punctuation like periods and slashes. In this case it is split between `https://gist.github.com/Glorfindel83` on one line and `/` followed by the hash on the next line (https://i.stack.imgur.com/JfKm3.png). My OS (or maybe the browser itself) doesn't allow resizing below a certain width so I can't make it narrow enough to actually require splitting the hash in the middle. In Chrome on Desktop I can however reproduce the issue.